# php - displaying error message based on uploading file size not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making basic uploading file code. User is only allowed to upload two types of files, word and excel, and the file size limit to upload is 2MB.

I try to upload the word file and is 1MB, it has successfully uploaded to the database. When I test the code, the error message based on the incorrect file format is displayed, so it works.

Now here is the problem. When i try to test it by uploading the file 5MB, that is above the limit 2MB, it displayed the message "Contract Form Sucessfully Submitted!", but the file is not uploaded to the database. It works but it displayed the message wrong when it supposed to be "Sorry. Your file is too large. Only 2MB is allowed.".

So what is going on here?

PHP:

```
if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){

    $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES['upload']['name']);
    $filedata= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
    $filetype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES['upload']['type']);
    $filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    $allowed =  array('zip','rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(in_array($ext, $allowed)){ 

        if($filesize < 2097152) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO contracts( `filename`,`filedata`,`filetype`,`filesize`,`created`) 
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $null = NULL;
            $stmt->bind_param("sbsis", $filename, $filedata, $filetype,$filesize,$created);
            $fp = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "r");

                while (!feof($fp)) {
                $stmt->send_long_data(18, fread($fp,$filesize));
                }
                fclose($fp);
            $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->errno){
                    echo "ERROR!!! " . $stmt->error;
                    } else {
                    $successMsg = "Contract Form Sucessfully Submitted!";
                    }
            $stmt->close(); 

        } else {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry. Your file is too large. Only 2MB is allowed.";
        }       
    } else {
        $errorMsg = "Sorry. Only zip, rar, pdf, doc & docx are allowed.";        
    }
} else {
        $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
        $query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`created`) 
                        VALUES (?)" ;

        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $created);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->errno){
        echo "ERROR!!! " . $stmt->error;

        } else {
       $successMsg = "Contract Form Sucessfully Submitted!";
        }
        $stmt->close();         
    }           
}   

$con->close(); 

?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
<html>
<body>

<form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                <?php
                if(isset($errorMsg)){
                ?>
                <?php echo $errorMsg; ?>

                <?php
                } else if(isset($successMsg)){
                ?>

                 <?php echo $successMsg; ?>

                <?php
                }
                ?>   

<label>Upload File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="upload" />

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Submit New Contract
                    </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi I found `max_file_size` and `post_max_size` but not `max_post_file_size`. Is `post_max_size` = `max_post_file_size`?

Comment: They are same @Hazirah_Halim

Comment: I set the `post_max_size` = 2M, yet it still not working. Why is that?

Comment: its the same @Hazirah_Halim , restart your php and (apache or nginx)

Comment: change both and set size more than your actual file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini.and set them something like this

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

then restart your web server and php

you can see them with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

also

Comment: It displayed Warning: POST Content-Length of 5603302 bytes exceeds the limit of 2097152 bytes in Unknown on line 0 but not "Sorry. Your file is too large. Only 2MB is allowed."

Comment: did you restarted your web server?

Comment: Yes and I change both and set size more than the actual file size. It works. Thanks a lot. I totally forgot about this method when i encounter the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add this piece of code right above your file input:

```
<html>
<body>

<form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                <?php
                if(isset($errorMsg)){
                ?>
                <?php echo $errorMsg; ?>

                <?php
                } else if(isset($successMsg)){
                ?>

                 <?php echo $successMsg; ?>

                <?php
                }
                ?>   

<label>Upload File</label>
                    <!-- the added code is here just above the input file type -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152">
                    <input type="file" name="upload" />

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Submit New Contract
                    </button>
</form>
</body>
```

Goodluck!